# how to kill a group of processes in clozure cl?

Tags: shell, lisp, kill, ccl

I want to run a shell command within ccl, but this command may be hung for some reason. So I want to kill all the sub process generated by this command. How can I do this?

I have tried trivial-shell to run the shell command, when the command not hung, it works well.

I also use with-timeout macro which is in trivial-shell to check the timeout, it just give me a timeout-error condition, the shell process is still hunging there. Here I just want to kill them all and return something.

Thank you all.

Comment: I would suggest to ask such a question on the Clozure CL mailing list - there are all the experts.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, `trivial-shell` only provides a synchronous shell call so there's no simple way to terminate ongoing subprocesses.

I suggest calling Clozure Common Lisp's implementation-specific `ccl:run-program` function with `:wait nil` to run the jobs asynchronously.  You can then call `ccl:signal-external-process` on the running process to kill it if you need.  [Documentation here](http://ccl.clozure.com/manual/chapter9.4.html#External-Program-Dictionary).